# Laravel 4.2 and Angularjs - should I use session_id or _token for preserving session

Tags: php, angularjs, session, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a test app (for now) and I am using Angularjs on the front and Laravel 4.2 on the back end.

On Angularjs side of things I need to somehow maintain session data for the logged in user and Laravel conveniently provides Session model.

```
$session = Session::all();
```

Output of that is something like this

```
Array
(
    [_token] => Jo9GGEaax6DLMBhzBLmU8SJAf1nquyZ1HWlSPY2o
    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc] => 1
)
```

I can also however access session ID.

```
$session_id = Session::getId();
echo $session_id;
```

which returns ... well ... session id,,,

```
ee7f050f7cb13a4de7dccd2e1f393204accb1068
```

I see both .. token (as data that is assigned to session) and session_id .. as values I can use to maintain the state I need,,, difference being that Session model allows me to store any key pair into the session and further manipulate session data (which can be useful..)

**Is there any advantage to using session ID versus relying on assigned TOKEN data to keep track of session state?**

What would be the reasoning behind one or the other choice?

Is there a concise resource I can look at that would make this decision easier for me?

Thanks!